# How to create signature using the previously created key and secret for access rest-api

Tags: java, http-signature

Currently, I am working on an API where only the access key and secret key are available. To access their API I need to generate the signature in algorithm="hmac-sha256.

They have some python code as an example like

```
response = requests.post('https://' + host + url_path,
                         json=body,
                         auth=HTTPSignatureAuth(algorithm="hmac-sha256",
                                                key=b64decode(key_secret_id),
                                                key_id=key_id,
                                                headers=[
                                                    '(request-target)', 'host',
                                                    'date', 'content-type',
                                                    'content-length'
                                                ]),
                         headers=headers)
```

But I am trying to access it using java and not getting any good library or suggestion to do same.

It will be very helpful if someone help me or suggest me any solution..

Comment: Because of HTTPS, HTTP request signing is today an obsolete technology. As far as I remember is was also used by oAuth v1 (dropped in v2), therefore you may find an implementation in some old oAuth v1 Java libraries.

Comment: You can take joauth as an example for oauth 1 signing, but it has some twitter specific restrictions, so it may need adaption. https://github.com/twitter/joauth/blob/3aab711e746c155b1a0359c7abb928ffeca2280e/src/main/java/com/twitter/joauth/Signer.java#L73-L109